# How to Splice array in Javascript without returning reversed data

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to JavaScript. I have an array:

```
var test = [
    {data1},
    {data2},
    {data3},
    {data4},
    {data5}
];
```

So what I did is

```
var test1 = [];
while(test.lenght){
    test1.push(test.splice(0-2));
}
```

But the result is

```
test1[0] = [{data4},{data5}];
test1[1] = [{data2},{data3}];
test1[2] = [{data1}];
```

I want to splice it into like this

```
test1[0] = [{data1},{data2}];
test1[1] = [{data3},{data4}];
test1[2] = [{data5}];
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `0-2` (-2) means two positions back from the end. Seems like a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method with arguments as `0` and `2` for removing first 2 elements.

```js
var test = [
  'data1',
  'data2',
  'data3',
  'data4',
  'data5'
];

var test1 = [];
while (test.length) {
  test1.push(test.splice(0, 2));
}

console.log(test1)
```

---

**UPDATE :** If you don't want to update the original array then use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method.

```js
var test = [
  'data1',
  'data2',
  'data3',
  'data4',
  'data5'
];

var test1 = [];
for (var i = 0, count = Math.ceil(test.length / 2); i < count; i++) {
  test1.push(test.slice(i * 2, i * 2 + 2));
}

console.log(test1)

// or alternate method with updated for loop conditions

var test2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i += 2) {
  test2.push(test.slice(i, i + 2));
}

console.log(test2)
```

Comment: that's what i did, but it return the other array and not the one that i expected.

Comment: @sse : check the output